# Is there a way to only show two labels on the x-axis in a scatterplot?

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a **scatterplot** that shows the age of people on the y-axis and the way they have been positioned on the x-axis (either 0° or 15° elevated).

My dataset is called raw.

I have used the function `plot(raw$position, raw$age)`. Instead of just showing 0 and 15, the x-axis gives out 0, 5, 10, 15 (with no dots for 5 or 10, since the only two positionings are 0 and 15°).

Is there a way to get it to only show my 0 and 15 on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't supply the original data below is a reproducible example with my own. There's two parts to doing this:

1. Include `yaxt = "n"` in `plot` to suppress the original y-axis in the plot
2. Use `axis(2, labels = c(0, 15), at = c(0, 15))` to set the y-axis (`side = 2`) with labels (`labels`) called c(0,15) at the points (`at`) on the axis (0,15).

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(
  age = round(runif(10, 20, 30)),
  position = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5)*15
)
plot(df$age, df$position, yaxt = "n")
axis(2, labels = c(0, 15), at = c(0, 15))
```

Edit: Just re-read your question and saw you want to edit the x-axis, which you do with this:

Same as above but now set `xaxt = "n"` and `side = 1`

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(
  age = round(runif(10, 20, 30)),
  position = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5)*15
)
plot(df$position, df$age, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, labels = c(0, 15), at = c(0, 15))
```